# Should I chain `get()`s in Ember, or can I use dot notation?

Tags: ember.js

Should I use:

```
this.get('controller').get('simpleSearch').get('selectedOptions').get('height')
```

or

```
this.get('controller.simpleSearch.selectedOptions.height')
```

I think the first is... verbose.  Is there any reason *not* to use the second method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in pursuit of an answer, I found this thread: [Definitive guide of when to use .get](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/definitive-guide-of-when-to-use-get/6789/8) on [discuss.emberjs.com](http://discuss.emberjs.com).

According to [gordon_kristan](http://discuss.emberjs.com/users/gordon_kristan)'s [answer](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/definitive-guide-of-when-to-use-get/6789/3):

> Always use get(), and use it in one of the following two ways:
>
> ```
> // If obj is guaranteed to not be null or undefined
> obj.get('very.deep.nested.property');
> // If obj might be null or undefined, or if it's not an Ember object,
> Ember.get(obj, 'very.deep.nested.property');
> ```
>
> Using get() is the only way to ensure that the Ember computed
>   properties will always function properly. For instance, in your
>   example, consider if model was a PromiseObject (which Ember-Data uses
>   quite a bit):
>
> ```
> // This will not work, since it won't activate the `unknownProperty` handler on `model`
> var startDate = parentView.controller.model.createdAt;
> // But this will work
> var startDate = Ember.get(parentView, 'controller.model.createdAt');
> ```

In addition, as [christopher](http://discuss.emberjs.com/users/christopher) points out:

> Using `obj.get('very.deeply.nested.property')` will only throw an
>   undefined error if `obj` is `undefined`. If any other property in the
>   chain is `undefined`, then the call to `get()` will simply return
>   `undefined`. If instead you called `get()` at every level, then it
>   would throw an error if any level was `undefined`.

If you want to read the source, check out [ember-metal/lib/property_get](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.3.0/packages/ember-metal/lib/property_get.js#L52).

Answer (score 3):

Can not remember where I read it on the ember site but they suggested the best solution was the dot notation.

```
this.get('controller.simpleSearch.selectedOptions.height')
```

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate the answer.  I'm going to let it stay open for a little bit, just in case someone else finds an official source, or something close.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Javascript/Browsers allow using the `.` notation without even having to do a `get`. You can also look into [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which allows you to allow `null` values to bubble without erroring.

For example:

```
// All 3 are identical
x = this.get("property").get("value");
x = this.get("property.value");
x = this.property.value;

// Error!
x = this.nonexistent_property.value

// Sets x to null
x = this.nonexistent_property?.value
```